# Align Android Relative Layout Items w/ Dynamic Size Item in Different Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I haven't been able to find anything out there on aligning a widget from a RelativeLayout to a widget within a horizontal LinearLayout.  Aligning from one layout to another is almost not even mentioned on the Internet.  I thought my question might be easiest explained with a picture.  Please pardon the crude drawing:

[image]

This really sums up what I'm trying to do.  The green is a relative layout and the blue is a horizontal linear layout with each item having a width of 'match_parent' and a weight of '1' for equal distribution across the linear layout - the purpose of this is to take advantage of wider screens and landscape mode by expanding items B-E, the most important information in my application.

I have a statically-sized image (A) to the left of the linear layout.  The linear layout is relatively-placed 5dp to the right of A.  Items B-D have a rightMargin of 8dp for spacing.  F is a pair of TextViews that are aligned to the start of A.  G is a pair of TextViews that are aligned to the right of the screen.

What I want to do is:

- Align the right (end) of F with the right (end) of B.
- Align the left (start) of G with the left (start) of C.
- Have this maintain this relationship as the device is rotated into landscape mode.

I have tried aligning the alignEnd, alignToEnd, and alignRight of the relative layout widgets to the widgets in the linear layout, but Android Studio rejects that since they're not siblings in a RelativeLayout.  I could do this programmatically and calculate it in a PreDrawListener (add width of A + 5dp + width of B), but I'd rather do it in the layout, if possible.

Here's my layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="210dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="155dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="22sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="185dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:paddingTop="-5dp"
        android:text="ID"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/age"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="155dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="185dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:paddingTop="-5dp"
        android:text="Age"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="159dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
                android:id="@+id/chart1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
                android:id="@+id/chart2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
                android:id="@+id/chart3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
                android:id="@+id/chart4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Is this possible?  Thanks.

Comment: Post your xml layout that you have tried so far

Comment: It is not possible to align `Views` across `ViewGroups`. My suggestion is that you try to remove the `LinearLayout` from the equation. Place all the `Views` inside the `RelativeLayout` and then you can properly align them. If that is not an option you can always just set the position and size of the `Views` you want to align programmatically. But finding a solution which just relys on xml is clearly preferable.

Comment: i would probably use a custom `ViewGroup` class with own `onLayout` method implementation

Comment: @Xaver, how can I allow B-E to expand if they're not in a horizontal LinearLayout?  Would they expand if I just set the margins around them?  This site doesn't seem great at posting XML unfortunately...

Comment: @pennstump Posting xml should be no problem. If it is somehow formatted badly then post it anyway, I can edit your question to format it properly. What do you mean by expand? Should B-E be equally spaced across the screen?

Comment: @XaverKapeller, By expanding I mean that if in portrait mode B,C,D,E may be 150dp wide with 8dp of margin between them, but if you go to landscape mode they should grow to fill the space, say 250dp width with the same 8dp margins (all flubbed numbers).

Comment: What IDE are you using? That xml is seriously messed up. There are tons of illegal characters in there like `” ` instead of `"`. Android Studio or IntellJ don't even recognise it as xml, much less a layout xml...

Comment: Sorry about that.  I'm in Android Studio, but to pull out the sensitive stuff I pasted into TextEdit on Mac and made my edits.  I'm going to try your approach from above, and attempt this without the LinearLayout.

Comment: Why would you do that? Edit in Android Studio. That's what it's for. I cannot imagine how tedious it must be to make those edits in TextEdit. Plus now you have XML that isn't even valid... I am almost finished fixing it, will edit the fixed version into your question once I am done.

Comment: Hey, thanks.  Sorry for the BS, but there are plenty of things I certainly can't post from my code and I didn't want to corrupt my codebase.  @XaverKapeller, I tried experimenting with all RelationalLayout, but I can't work out how to get the B-E layouts to stretch.  I tried setting android:layout_toRightOf tags with margins and both minWidths and maxWidths, but since each layout has items that request 'match_parent' B takes up the whole screen.

Comment: B should be `wrap_content`. See my answer for more details. And you cannot get that stretching behaviour just from a `RelativeLayout`. You need a `LinearLayout` with `layout_weight` for that. The only other option is to set the size and position of the `Views` programmatically.

Comment: I haven't experienced them yet, but do you think `TableLayout` will solve the OP question?

Comment: @ChadiAbouSleiman I doubt it, `TableLayout` is pretty bad. A `RelativeLayout` is the best bet. The OP could keep his current layout if he would just set the size and position of the `Views` outside of the `LinearLayout` which should be aligned with `Views` in the `LinearLayout` programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here's how I solved it:

```
// Pre-Draw Task
ViewTreeObserver userImageVTO = userImage.getViewTreeObserver();
userImageVTO.addOnPreDrawListener( new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    public boolean onPreDraw() {

        // Set Alignment Widths
        name.setWidth( imageView.getWidth() + ( ( imageView.getWidth() / 150 ) * 5 ) + chart1.getWidth() );  // Get the Pixel Density (Since Image is 150dp) for 5dp of Padding
        age.setWidth( chart1.getWidth() );

        return true;
    }
});
```

This is in my custom ListAdapter's getView().  I calculated the width of F with the known-sized imageView (150dp square) and padding (5dp) plus the retrieved width of chart1.  Then, in the XML I added this to G:

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/age"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
```

That allows G to expand/contract on rotation since it's set to always be 8dp to the right of F.